# Как создать id после создания createElement('div')

Tags: javascript

Как создать id после создания `createElement('div')`

```
var div = document.createElement('div');

div.className = "panel-tag"; // создал класс
```

А как создать в этом div id?

Answer (score 5):

Сoздание id у созданного элемента:

1. Способ 1

   ```
   var newElement = document.createElement('tagName');
   newElement.id = 'idName';
   ```
2. Способ 2

   ```
   var newElement = document.createElement('tagName');
   newElement.setAttribute('id','idName')
   ```

Comment: А есть какая-нибудь разница между этим способом и соседним ответом?

Comment: @andreymal никакой

Comment: @andreymal, в данном конкретном случае разницы может и не быть, но в общем случае установка свойства и установка атрибута могут быть не связаны, например свойство и атрибут checked

Answer (score 3):

```
div.setAttribute('id','idName')
```

Comment: Спасибо, Алексей работает!